# React router dom doesn't work with webpack

Tags: webpack, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using react-router v4. When I make the build of my app it seems that it doesn't work any more and in the browser URL always appear the root address, and if I write other route, like '/products', it tries to render this page but it always redirect to the home page. I want to say that if I push the buttons inside the app all works fine, but the URL never changes.

I make the 'push' action in the react router redux, but it still doesn't work. I read some of similar issues where says that I have to add something in my webpack configuration like 'historyApiFallback', but nothing works. In other parts says that I have to add '', but doesn't work neither. [Here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671) says that I have to use the method 'withRouter' of react-router, but I applied it and nothing change.

I am using webpack 2.3.2, react-router-dom 4.0.0-beta.8 and react-router-redux 5.0.0-alpha.4

So, what I am doing wrong?

Here my webpack server config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {
  "sendmail": "sendmail"
};

fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function(x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function(mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

const config = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../source/server.jsx')],
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../built/server'),
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://pos.lisapp.co:3001/' : 'http://localhost:3001/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['latest-minimal', 'react'],
          env: {
            production: {
              plugins: ['transform-regenerator', 'transform-runtime'],
              presets: ['es2015']
            },
            development: {
              presets: ['latest-minimal']
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'css-loader/locals?modules'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|source)\/(?!(react-table)\/).*/,
        loader: 'css-loader/locals?modules'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|source)\/(?!(react-touch-screen-keyboard)\/).*/,
        loader: 'css-loader/locals?modules'
      },
      {
        test: /\.inline.svg$/,
        loaders: [ 'babel-loader',
          {
            loader: 'react-svg-loader',
            query: {
              svgo: {
                plugins: [{removeTitle: false}],
                floatPrecision: 2
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|^(?!.*\.inline\.svg$).*\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=400000'
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  externals: nodeModules,
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.json'],
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    dns: 'mock',
    net: 'mock',
    child_process: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '../statics/styles.css',
      ignoreOrder: true,
    })
  ]
  // watch: true,
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      mangle: {
        except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require']
      }
    })
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Here my webpack client config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, '../source/client.jsx')],
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../built/statics'),
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://pos.lisapp.co:3001/' : 'http://localhost:3001/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2016', 'es2017', 'react'],
          plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'],
          env: {
            production: {
              plugins: ['transform-regenerator', 'transform-runtime'],
              presets: ['es2015']
            },
            development: {
              plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs']
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?modules',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|source)\/(?!(react-table)\/).*/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|source)\/(?!(react-touch-screen-keyboard)\/).*/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader',
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.inline.svg$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader!react-svg-loader?' + JSON.stringify({
          svgo: {
            // svgo options
            plugins: [{removeTitle: false}],
            floatPrecision: 2
          }
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|^(?!.*\.inline\.svg$).*\.svg$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=400000'
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  target: 'web',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.json'],
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    dns: 'mock',
    net: 'mock',
    child_process: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '../statics/styles.css',
      ignoreOrder: true,
    })
  ]
  // watch: true,
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      mangle: {
        except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require']
      }
    })
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for someone that face this same issue, the problem is about the preset used in babel, because React Router v4, works better with ES6. So, in this case we have to change the Uglify plugin with [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/blob/v1.0.0-beta.2/README.md#uglifyoptions), and import it at the top of the code as following:

```
const Uglify = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
```

And change this part of the Uglify plugin code:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false
  },
  mangle: {
    except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require']
  }
})
```

to this:

```
new Uglify({
  uglifyOptions: {
    ie8: false,
    ecma: 6,
    warnings: false
  }
})
```

You can make more optimizations here, but for me these are the basic options.

Also, you can change your 'routes' code to commonjs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Any routing package in react fails to work in webpack-generated projects, because  webpack simply doesn't know what to serve on this path.

webpack only knows about the root path for your application. To make it work, you need to tell webpack and its configuration that it should fallback for every path to your entry point. Simply add the following lines in your webpack config file:

```
 module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};
```

Happy Coding :)